# Traverse XML document using asp

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I'm trying to find if a certain element is present in a XML file and if it is, remove it. However I keep getting this error:

```
Description: Type mismatch: 'NodeList'
```

My code looks like this:

```
<%@ Language=VbScript%>
<%

Dim address

Set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
xmlDoc.async = False
xmlDoc.load (Server.MapPath("XML/sensor.xml"))

Set Root = XMLDoc.documentElement 

Set NodeList = Root.getElementsByTagName("sensor")

For Each i In NodeList

    if ((NodeList(i).getElementsByTagName("Address")(0).childNodes(0).nodeValue)=request.form("remove_address")) then
    NodeList.parentNode.removeChild NodeList 
    End if
Next



NodeList.parentNode.removeChild NodeList 
xmlDoc.Save "\www./XML/sensores.xml"

Response.Redirect("remove_sensor_modbus.html")

%>
```

And the XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sensors>
<sensor>
    <Address>40000</Address>
</sensor>
<sensor>
    <Address>46999</Address>
</sensor>
</sensors>
```

The form is a dropdown menu populated with this same XML file. 
Does anyone knows what could be causing this error?

Comment: Is this the complete XML? If so, you're missing the closing `</sensors>` element. Also, why are you using traditional ASP? If you have access to ASP.NET, I recommend you to use that instead.

Comment: The XmL was complete but it wasn't correctly displayed. Don't know why. I would use ASP.NET if I could, but I'm stuck with a legacy webserver that only supports classic ASP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have several errors in your loop. Try this:

```
Dim removeAddress
Set removeAddress = Request.Form("remove_address")

For Each sensorNode In NodeList
    Dim addressNode
    Set addressNode = sensorNode.GetElementsByTagName("Address")(0)

    If (addressNode.Text = removeAddress) Then
        sensorNode.RemoveChild(addressNode)
    End if
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. Just had to do a minor change instead of "sensorNode.RemoveChild(addressNode)" i used "sensorNode.parentNode.removeChild sensorNode" because it just removed the text leaving an empty node, that caused the script to crash if it was used more than once.